# Add "chapter" word into TOC using tocbibind package

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, tocloft, tocbibind

I want to add "Chapter" word before chapter number in Table of Content. I have searched the solutions but the most answered question is when we using tocloft package that I didn't use. Can I give that word when using tocbibind package?

Comment: Why don't you use `tocloft` then? Both packages are maintained by our fellow user Will Robertson and are compatible to each other,but do address different issues. `tocbibind` is basically only for the inclusion toc in toc, whereas `tocloft` does provide hooks to the toc - entries

Answer (score 1):

The hard part was getting the hanging indentation right.

```
\documentclass{report}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \settowidth{\@tempdimb}{\normalsize\bfseries \chaptername~}%
      \advance\leftskip by \@tempdimb
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@tempdima
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      \chaptername~#1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long title}

\end{document}
```

[image: toc with chapter]

Comment: How can I remove the word 'chapter' before the list of figures ?

Comment: @S_25 - Save and restore the original \l@chapter.  Or just put the redefinition inside a group {...} with the TOC (but not the LOF).

Comment: @JohnKormylo could you please show how to implement this for only chapters without the lists; example: list of figures, and appendices?

Comment: @AhmedSayed - As it turns out, my previous comment was invalid, since you have no control of \l@chapter while the TOC is being printed. One would need a way to distinguish between two different kinds of chapters. You might try asking a new question with a complete MWE.

Comment: @john kormylo I have already created a new question through this link https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499707/add-chapter-word-into-toc-page-number?noredirect=1#comment1262176_499707