# How can I edit the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents

I have:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{chapter name}
\section{section name}
\subsection{subsection name}
\end{document}
```

I get
[image]

I want to add the word 'Chapter' before the number 1 where it is written chapter name.
I want also to add a point line in front of the chapter name like in the section line.

I try to use this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand*\contentsname{Contents}}

\titlecontents{chapter}[5.3em]
{\vspace{0.3cm}}
{\contentslabel[\textbf{\chaptername~\thecontentslabel}]{5.3em}}
{\hspace*{-5.3em}}
{\titlerule{1pc}{.}\contentspage}[\smallskip]

\titlecontents{section}[5.3em]
{\smallskip}
{\thecontentslabel\enspace}
{\hspace*{-5.3em}}
{\hfill\contentspage}

\titlecontents{subsection}[6.92em]
{\smallskip}
{\thecontentslabel\enspace}
{\hspace*{-6.92em}}
{\hfill\contentspage}

    \begin{document}

    \tableofcontents
    \newpage

    \chapter*{Preface}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}
    \chapter{Looking-Glass House}
\section{A First section}
\section{Another section}
\subsection{A subsection}
    \end{document}
```

But I have this:
[image]

I have problem with the dotted line and I want that tha chapter nae be bold !

Comment: I think we have a lot of questions on this here, please have a look first

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278804/add-chapter-word-into-toc-using-tocbibind-package?s=2|1.2481

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to do it with `titletoc`. Note you'll have to redo the formatting of lower level sectioning titles (mainly the horizontal spacing) to make the layout consistent. The lengths may have to be adjusted depending on the document font, the font size, &c.

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{book}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{fourier, erewhon, cabin}
    %\usepackage{newtxtext}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
    \usepackage{titletoc}
    \usepackage{lipsum} \addto\captionsenglish{ \renewcommand*\contentsname{\centerline{Table of contents}}}

    \titlecontents{chapter}
    [5.5em] %5.3
    {\bigskip}
    {\contentslabel[\bfseries\textsc{\chaptername}~\thecontentslabel]{5.5em}\textbf}%\thecontentslabel
    {\hspace*{-5.5em}\textbf}% unnumbered chapters
    {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}[\smallskip]%
%
 \titlecontents{section}
 [5.5em] % i
 {\smallskip}
 {\thecontentslabel\enspace}%\thecontentslabel
 {\hspace*{-5.5em}}
 {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}%]

 \titlecontents{subsection}
 [7.12em] %
 {\smallskip}
 {\thecontentslabel\enspace}%\thecontentslabel
 {\hspace*{7.12em}}
 {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}

    \begin{document}

    \tableofcontents
    \newpage

    \chapter*{Preface}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}
    \chapter{Looking-Glass House}
\section{A First section}
\section{Another section}
\subsection{A subsection}
    \lipsum[1]
    \chapter{The Garden of Live Flowers}
    \lipsum[2-5]
    \chapter{Looking-Glass Insects}
    \lipsum[6]
    \chapter{Tweedledum and Tweedledee}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I delete page framing?

Comment: Remove the `[showframe]` option of geometry. It was there only to check the alignment at the left margin.

Comment: okay. Is it possible to add the points in the rest of the line and to put the font of the contents like the font of the book (Times) ?

Comment: I want to remove also the subsections please. Thank you very much

Comment: Do you mean adding the dotted line for chapters? As for the font, it's only because I started from an old template. Replace `\usepackage{fourier, erewhon,cabin} with `\usepackage{times}`. However, note `times` is obsolete, as it doesn't change the maths fonts. Unless you have absolutely no maths to write, it's better to load `newtxtext` and `newtxmath`, based on `TeX Gyre Termes`, a Times-clone.

Comment: Concerning the subsections, you have to remove `\titlecontents{subsection}{…}` (which  gets useless) and add in the preamble `\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}`.

Comment: Yes I want to add the dotted line for chapters, sections and subsections ?

Comment: I've edited my answer to explain that: replace `\hfill` with `\titlerule{1pc}{.}`. 1pc (1 pica) is the distance between consecutive dots. You can change this value.

Comment: I've edited my question. As you can see I have a problem in the dotted line. I want also that the chapter name be bold.

Comment: Only the word ‘Chapter’ or the chapter title too?

Comment: Both in bold: the word 'chapter' and the chapter title. How can I modify the problem of the dooted line please ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61053/discussion-between-bernard-and-s-25).