# Adding 'Chapter 1' instead of '1' and 'Appendix A' instead of 'A' to the Contents page in in Masters/Doctoral Thesis template

Tags: table-of-contents, templates

I have downloaded the latex template for doctoral thesis available in https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis.
In the content page, the chapters and appendices appears as:

1. Introduction
2. Methods...

A (Appendix title)

B (Appendix title)

But instead I would like to have them as follows:

Chapter 1. Intrduction

Chapter 2. Methods

Appendix A

Appendix B

Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If your question related to this link? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376596/how-can-i-edit-the-table-of-contents

Comment: Thanks @fdireito for the suggestion. It worked.