# Add “chapter” word into TOC --- Page number

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, templates, tocbibind

I am tired of not successfully doing it right !! I am working on my thesis and I am using this template https://github.com/kks32/phd-thesis-template/. However, there are some changes I need to implement and I could not successfully do it myself.

1. I need to add the word chapter before the chapter number and chapter name in the table of content (using tocbibind package). This part is similar to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278804/add-chapter-word-into-toc-using-tocbibind-package). I already tried this code before but it added the word chapter before every level-1 heading and I want it to be limited to only the main chapters without the list of figures, acronyms or even the appendices.

below is the MWE:

```
       \documentclass{report}
       \usepackage{tocbibind}

       \begin{document}
       \tableofcontents

       \section{test 1}
        First document. This is a simple example, with no 
          extra parameters or packages included.
        \end{document}
```

[image: before the word Chapter is added]

I then added the following code to the template, it executed and gave what I want yet there is the word chapter before every level-one title in the TOC.

```
     \makeatletter
     \renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
     \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
     \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
     \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
     \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
     \begingroup
     \settowidth{\@tempdimb}{\normalsize\bfseries \chaptername~}%
     \advance\leftskip by \@tempdimb
     \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
     \parfillskip -\@tempdima
     \leavevmode \bfseries
     \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
     \hskip -\leftskip
     \chaptername~#1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
     \penalty\@highpenalty
     \endgroup
     \fi}
     \makeatother
```

Below is the last version after modification:

```
   \documentclass{report}
   \usepackage{tocbibind}

 \makeatletter
 \renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
 \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
 \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
 \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
 \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
 \begingroup
 \settowidth{\@tempdimb}{\normalsize\bfseries \chaptername~}%
 \advance\leftskip by \@tempdimb
 \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
 \parfillskip -\@tempdima
 \leavevmode \bfseries
 \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
 \hskip -\leftskip
 \chaptername~#1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
 \penalty\@highpenalty
 \endgroup
 \fi}
 \makeatother


 \begin{document}
  \tableofcontents

  \chapter{Test 1}
   First document. This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included.
   \end{document}
```

[image: After Implementing the code (After the Word Chapter is Added)]

2. In chapters first pages, there are no page numbers and I want the page number to be visible at the top right of the page... I have been trying to figure out where is the exact code that suppresses the page number from being visible at the chapter title page with no success.

Comment: Could you post a minimal, yet compilable , code?

Comment: @Bernard Excuse me !! could you please specify what do you want specifically ?! I am sorry i cant understand how minimal!?

Comment: Just something short reproducing your problems. I have small idea concerning the page number on first pages of chapters, but I need to know which class options you have set (such as two-sided or one-sided, open right or open any, &c.)

Comment: @bernard excuse me i forgot to mention that! I am using the one sided option

Comment: @Bernard and i am not using fencyheaders

Comment: Same comment as to your last question that you have deleted, this is the definition of a minimal working example: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that. Maybe read it completely and the modify your question.

Comment: @dr. Manuel thank you

Comment: @dr. Manuel and as per my question i am using a template and this template has many long files that is very hard to post on the question, that's why i refered to the template link. My question is how to modify the template (the original tocbibind class ) to add the word chapter in the toc. Do you mean i shall post the source code of the tocbibind class?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Is this what you mean? Correct me if i am mistaken !!?? Thank you !!

Comment: Currently \chapter changes the pagestyle to plain on the first page.  Most people use fancyhdr and `\fancypagestyle{plain}{...}`.  That isn;t the only way, but it is the simplest approach.

Comment: @john kormylo i am sorry could you please indicate the other ways?! This method is not working properly with me!! I am not using any page style!!

Comment: I would imagine this 5o be a part of the tocloft package. Tocbibind has nothing to do with toc formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the aux file I noticed that normal chapters used `\numberline` and others didn't.  So I moved the addition of `\chaptername` to be inside `\numberline`.

```
\documentclass{report}
   \usepackage{tocbibind}

 \makeatletter
 \renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
 \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
 \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
 \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
 \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
 \begingroup
   \let\oldnumberline=\numberline
   \def\numberline{\chaptername~\oldnumberline}%
   \settowidth{\@tempdimb}{\normalsize\bfseries \chaptername~}%
   \advance\leftskip by \@tempdimb
   \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
   \parfillskip -\@tempdima
   \leavevmode \bfseries
   \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
   \hskip -\leftskip
   #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
   \penalty\@highpenalty
 \endgroup
 \fi}

 \def\ps@plain{% first page of a chapter
      \def\@oddhead{\normalfont\hfil\thepage}%
      \let\@evenhead\@oddhead
      \let\@oddfoot\@empty
      \let\@evenfoot\@empty}
 \makeatother


 \begin{document}
  \tableofcontents

  \chapter{Test 1}
   First document. This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included.
   \end{document}
```

---

This solution adds the chapter/appendix name (`\@chapapp`) inside `\addcontentsline`.  It uses a separate call to `\addtocontents` to set the indentation for long titles.

```
\documentclass{report}
   \usepackage{tocbibind}
   \usepackage{appendix}

\newlength{\tocindent}

 \makeatletter
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \settowidth{\tocindent}{\normalsize\bfseries \@chapapp\space}% complute additonal indentation
                         \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\tocindent=\the\tocindent}% store in TOC
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                                   {\@chapapp~\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}

\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \advance\leftskip\tocindent% only change
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\hfil
      \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2%
                                 \kern-\p@\kern\p@}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}

 \def\ps@plain{% first page of chapter
      \def\@oddhead{\normalfont\hfil\thepage}%
      \let\@evenhead\@oddhead
      \let\@oddfoot\@empty
      \let\@evenfoot\@empty}
 \makeatother


 \begin{document}
  \tableofcontents

  \chapter{Test 1}
   First document. This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included.

  \chapter{This is a very long chapter title, which goes on and on until the next line}

  \appendix
  \def\chaptername{Appendix}
  \chapter{Test 2}
   \end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked for me !! could you update it for the community to exclude the appendices as well !!
Appendices have \numberline as well !! yet the word Appendix is written before the \number line in the aux file

Comment: That would require an entirely different approach, changing the \definition of \chapter or perhaps \addcontentsline instead of \l@chapter.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion using package `tocbasic`:

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocbibind}

\usepackage{tocbasic}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  entrynumberformat=\entrywithprefix{\chaptername},
  dynnumwidth
]{tocline}{chapter}
\newcommand*\entrywithprefix[2]{#1~#2}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Foo}

\section{Bar}
First document. This is a simple example, with no 
extra parameters or packages included.
\end{document}
```

Run three times to get

[image]