# How to format table of contents (ToC) that conform with my university's format?

Tags: table-of-contents, thesis

I am writing my thesis according to my university's format. I want to add "CHAPTER" in front of the chapter's number and "TABLE OF CONTENTS", "TITLE" and "PAGE" on top of the table of contents. I need to change the indentation of "LIST OF PUBLICATION" too. The following is my working trial:

```
% The content is   actually not a thesis.
% Texts, math. formula, tables, diagrams and graphics
% are there to show the physical thesis formatting
% and how to  obtain the required format

\makeatletter
\let\my@xfloat\@xfloat
\makeatother

\documentclass[oneside,12pt,a4paper]{book}
%\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{UTMThesis, enumerate, amsfonts, longtable, qtree, etoolbox, array, rotating, pgf, tikz, tikz-cd, algorithm, csquotes}

\makeatletter
\def\@xfloat#1[#2]{
    \my@xfloat#1[#2]%
    \def\baselinestretch{1}%
    \@normalsize \normalsize
}
\makeatother

\allowdisplaybreaks
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, matrix, positioning, shapes, shapes.geometric, calc, intersections, decorations.pathreplacing}
\newcommand{\tikznode}[2]{\relax
    \ifmmode%
    \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {$#2$};
    \else
    \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {#2};%
    \fi}
\let\openbox\relax
\let\iint\relax
\let\iiint\relax
\let\iiiint\relax
\let\idotsint\relax

\newcommand*{\qed}{\hfill\ensuremath{\square}}


%-------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{cite}[sort] % change  cite from [1,2,3] to [1-3] etc for number system
\makeatletter                        % change from
  \renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{#1.}  % [1] to 1. etc 
\makeatother                         % in list of references
%-----------------------------------------------------------
  \setlength{\voffset}{-2.1cm}
  \setlength{\hoffset}{-.4cm}  
%--------------------------------------------------------
\font\fiverm=cmr5 \input{Pictex.tex} % using pictex
%---------------------------------------------------------
%\pagestyle{plain}
%-------------------------------------------------------
  \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \pagestyle{fancy}
  \lhead{}
  \chead{}
  \rhead{}
  \lfoot{}  
  \cfoot{\vspace{-.35cm}\thepage}  % 
  \rfoot{} 
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
%-------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
  \input{frontmatter/FrontTitle}
  \input{frontmatter/Validation.tex}
  \input{frontmatter/SupervisorDeclaration.tex}
  \input{frontmatter/Title.tex}
  \input{frontmatter/Declaration.tex}
  \input{frontmatter/Dedication.tex}
  \input{frontmatter/Acknowledgement.tex}
  \input{frontmatter/Abstract.tex}
  \input{frontmatter/Abstrak.tex}
  \tableofcontents
  \input{frontmatter/TableofContents(Final).tex}  
  %\input{TableofContents(Final1).tex}
  \input{frontmatter/ListofTables(Final).tex} 
  \input{frontmatter/ListofFigures(Final).tex}  
  \input{frontmatter/ListofAbbreviations.tex}
  \input{frontmatter/ListofSymbols.tex}
\mainmatter
  \input{main/Chap1.tex}        %Chapter1
  \input{main/Chap2.tex}        %Chapter2
  \input{DummyChapter.tex}
  \input{main/Chap3.tex}        %Chapter3
  \input{DummyChapter.tex}
  \input{main/Chap4.tex}        %Chapter4
  \input{DummyChapter.tex}
  \input{main/Chap5.tex}    
  \input{main/Chap6.tex}    %Chapter5
  \input{main/Chap7.tex}
  \input{ThesisRefUTMn(Final).tex}%
  \input{DummyChapter.tex}
```

which produces:

[image]
[image]
[image]

The university' format looks like this:

[image]
[image]

All the files (the styles, packages, figures, etc) have been uploaded as a project in Overleaf and can be obtained through this link:

> https://www.overleaf.com/7133235792wywzqqjwmgtm

Please help.

Comment: the page on overleaf is restricted

Comment: I've edited the link so that it can be viewed and edited @jsbibra

Comment: Your objective isn't entirely clear. Specifically, why does your code contain both detailed instructions to write chapter- and section-level entries to the toc (table of contents) *and* contain a `\tableofcontents` directive? Would you be ok with a solution that predefines the desired format of the ToC and a single `\tableofcontents` directive -- and thus does away with most `\contentsline` directives? Please advise.

Comment: Yes, I'm ok with a solution that predefines the desired format of the ToC and a single \tableofcontents directive @Mico

Comment: Parts of you question have appeared before: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499707/add-chapter-word-into-toc-page-number and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191182/adding-different-kinds-of-entities-to-table-of-contents for example.